# javascript object to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i'm trying to send an js object to a php function using `jquery.ajax`.

This is what i have so far:

js side:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   url: url,
   data: {persoon : persoon2},
   async: false,
   success: function(){
     alert(data);
   return true;
   }
 });
```

php side:

```
$decode = json_decode($_GET["persoon"]);
$verzekering->setVoornaam($decode->persoon_voornaam);
```

in js this works: `persoon2.persoon_voornaam`
but i can't get to the value in php, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: More detail, please. **Specifically** what isn't working? What's happening, and how does that differ from what _should_ be happening?

Comment: i should pass the value to setVoornaam, but $decode->persoon_voornaam is empty or wrong. The setVoornaam part works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem(s)

1. I was using this inside Drupal and the Jquery version was still 1.2.6. Upgrading it resolved a lot of the problems
2. The string i tried to catch with the $_GET["persoon"] was mall formated becaus i just send along a js object. Changing

   data: {persoon : persoon2},

to

```
data: {persoon:JSON.stringify(persoon2)},
```

fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

few fixes

```
data: "persoon=persoon2", // check input format
success: function(data) { // missing data argument
```

EDIT your ajax code is working (check URL or php code)

http://jsfiddle.net/ish1301/KZndE/

Comment: if i do  data: {persoon : persoon2.persoon_voornaam}, it does work

Comment: yes, i get an alert but it is empty. Even when i do echo 'some text'.

Comment: it now looks like this   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   return true;
   }

Comment: url is ok, i thought the problem was in the php but i don't know what the problem is

Comment: post absolute url from where you are requesting data